# Restore UINavigationbar shadowImage

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

Is there an elegant way to undo `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()`

for the next viewcontroller that was pushed on stack so that it shows the original shadow image?

Comment: Here is the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57401651/how-to-add-a-border-to-swift-navigationbar-after-removing-it/57401747#57401747

Answer (score 0):

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil
```