# How to add a border to swift navigationBar after removing it

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, navigationbar, navigationcontroller

I use:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

to remove the border of a navigationBar earlier in my app but now I'm not sure to add the border back on a later screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To reset the `navigationBar`'s `shadowImage` to the default `shadowImage` do the following:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UINavigationBar().shadowImage
```